# React Native Typescript: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"solid" | "clear" | "outline"'.ts(2322)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am using TypeScript alongside with React Native.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';
import { IThemedButton } from '../../../models/themedButton';

interface IThemedButtonProps {
  data: IThemedButton;
}

const ThemedButton: React.FC<IThemedButtonProps> = ({
  data: { title, type, onPress },
}) => {
  return <Button title={title} type={type} onPress={onPress} />;
};

export default ThemedButton;

export interface IThemedButton {
  title: string;
  type: string;
  onPress: any;
}
```

I set type to string, because the button title is a string, but VS Code shows me an error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"solid" | "clear" | "outline"'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(326, 3): The expected type comes from property 'type' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Button> & Readonly<ButtonProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

I read in the docs, that the type is optional:
https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/button.html#type

What can be the solution?

Answer (score 3):

The only 3 things that `type` can be are "solid", "clear", or "outline", so TypeScript wants those defined as the types. Even though they are strings, for some reason TypeScript wants those to be defined as "solid", "clear", or "outline.

```
export interface IThemedButton {
  title: string;
  type: 'solid' | 'clear' | 'outline';
  onPress: any;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a brief description on what your code is doing/how it solves the issue.

Comment: The only 3 things that type can be are "solid", "clear", or "outline", so TypeScript wants those defined as the types. Even though they are strings, for some reason TypeScript wants those to be defined as "solid", "clear", or "outline."

Answer (score 0):

Here type is enum with values ["solid", "clear", "outline"]

try adding any of these and The expected type comes from property 'type'

so code will be

```
export interface IThemedButton {
  title: string;
  type: type;
  onPress: any;
}
```